# Enterprise Architect all diagram fonts changed

Tags: fonts, enterprise-architect

Hi this morning I logged in our architecture repository in Sparx Enterprise Architect and all diagrams that I open have a large font which corrupts the diagram layouts. This is a massive damage to our repository as our documentation is generated from the repository. I assume there was a central setting changed by someone with admin priviledge, such as the Tools->Options->Diagram->Appearance->"Configure Default Element Fonts".

My questions are specifically:

a) is this a good assumption? [Edit 21.9.17: resetting defaults for the User Font works right after reset. BUT, on the next day when the usere restarts his client, the Fonts are messed up again, so basically this is not a good assumption.]

b) **what is the default font&size that I should set back**: I have a backup of our existing system, but I can't see to current font setting. [Edit 21.9.17: thanks for the answers, the correct font is Arial 8 in our case].

[I had to edit, as I am not so sure of my previous statement anymore, I believe I had some comparison issues with zoom-levels of my diagrams].

What I am missing is this Dialog in our installation, this is mentioned in all the Sparx Docs, but I cannot find it. We can only set User Font on our system (the upper Frame of the Dialog is missing, same as in Thomas Kilian answer).
[image: Setting Default Fonts]

Comment: In EA 13 my default font is "Calibri", font size 8.5

Answer (score 1):

To amend OP's answer: The font in the project settings is stored in the table `usys_system` where `Property` is either `FontName` or `FontSize` and `Value` containing the setting. For defaults these keys are simply not present.

---

**Original answer**

The diagram font is stored in the registry under

```
\\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sparx Systems\EA400\EA\OPTIONS\FONTNAME
\\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sparx Systems\EA400\EA\OPTIONS\FONTSIZE
```

The default for 12.1 is Arial 8. There's an option to reset the font in this dialog:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas, this is something we found to fix the problem for individual Users, unfortunately it comes back on the next day. What I have been wondering is why I don't see a "Model Font" in this dialog: if I read the Sparx documentation, this Default Model Font is mentioned everywhere and there is even a screenshot of the dialog you inserted above whith an additional Frame for the "Model Font".

Comment: Hmm. You should describe this "comes back on the next day" in your question in more detail (please use the edit link). What are the steps/what do you see?

Comment: Actually in my Installation these FONTNAME and FONTSIZE settings are under:
\\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sparx Systems\EA400\EA\OPTIONS

Comment: Oops. You are right. I skipped some lines in the export :-/ Will make a correction.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well after speaking with sparx-support the setting I was looking for seems to be in the Project|Settings|Project Options > General. I believe this will solve our problem since there was a wrong fontsize (10) configured there and clearing the setting fixed the issue for two users I am in contact with.

[image: Model Font for a project]

Comment: Happy you figured it out. EA's user interface is very "unique". We call it EAUI - EA Unique Interface.